# Three Different text to call the same onclick action

Tags: php, javascript

I have this code working alright (all thanks to all the kind assistance i have received in this medium

```
$htx = $row['mia_Text'] == 'mia owo';


 <div id='inner'>
          <p style="color:#FFF;"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="pkgsPopup('<?='http://'.$hLnk?>');" rel='nofollow'>
            <?=$hTxt?>
            </a> </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id='innercontent'>
      ....
```

Assuming I aslo want to (apart from $htx = $row['mia_Text'] == 'mia owo') add another mia_Text like 'mia ekpo' and 'mia uman' to the same $htx onclick event, any ideas on how I can implement this?

I really appreciate all the help.
Thanks

Comment: Think he's been asking the same question

Comment: I didn't get that. What do you mean add another mia_Text like ,,,? you wanna set three different values through on button's click?

Comment: If you want help with JavaScript, post the rendered HTML (the server-side script is *irrelevant*, and confuses the question).

Answer (score 0):

While I'm really not sure what your asking or whether that code is php or javascript, but I think what you're asking is how do you compare $row['mia_Text'] to more than one condition. If that is in fact what you're asking you could just write

```
$htx = (
    $row['mia_Text'] == 'mia owo' || 
    $row['mia_Text'] == 'mia ekpo' || 
    $row['mia_Text'] == 'mia uman'
)
```

There's simpler ways of writing that using, but that code should work in either php or javascript.

Comment: Thanks hobberwickey for helping. I really appreciate it.

Comment: If that's what you were asking, here on stackoverflow you should accept the answer (gives me points) if not, clarify your question in the comments.